# Espresso boolean function optimization in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I need to optimize boolean function that has more than 20 variables in the body and that must be done fast. I tried Quine–McCluskey algorithm, it is not good enough when number of variables is greater than 10. I read that Espresso method can handle greater number of variables without significant overhead. Is there a java lib that implements this algorithm? I'll appreciate any feedback.

Comment: what is fast for you?

Comment: few seconds, up to half a minute

Comment: Not sure if there is a *library*, but use of Espresso is documented here: http://www.uic.edu/classes/ece/ece465/06/tools/A%20short%20introduction%20to%20Espresso.pdf and also on its main page on Berkeley's Center for Electronic System Design here http://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/pubs/downloads/espresso/

Comment: I just found one: https://github.com/Rupan/espresso but it uses JNI to original espresso library